# Different default currency for different users in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have one question that is related to salesforce, I know that I can change the default currency for my whole organization, but can I put a default currency for different users? so that when a user A logins, he sees the currency as dollars, and when user B logins, he sees pounds, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by [enabling](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003638&type=1) multi-currency (can't be disabled once enabled). You'd set a Corporate Currency and then for the users that are using a currency different from the Corporate, you can set their [User (Personal) Currency](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_currency_set_personal.htm&language=en_US&type=0).